# C - Limit the string length

Tags: c, arrays, loops

(Sorry for my bad english !)

I wrote a program that asks you to type a password no longer than a certain number, eight characters in this case. The characters that pass the limit will be cut out from the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXCHAR 8

main()
{
    char password[MAXCHAR];
    int i;
    char c;

    printf("Insert password: MAX 8 CHARS!\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i <= MAXCHAR; i++){
        c = getchar();

        if(i == MAXCHAR){
            break;
        }
        else{
            password[i] = c;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", password);
}
```

So the program works BUT there is a "strange" problem. If the limit IS EIGHT and I type a password longer than eight characters 
(Example: P455w0rds98) 
the output will be like this:

```
P455w0rd☺
```

So it puts a smiley at the end and I don't know why. It happens only if a the limit is established at eight.

Comment: Slight correction (no offence): You mean "asks you to **type** a password" ("digit" has a different meaning and is quite irritating here).

Comment: You should read more about **getchar**.

Comment: Olaf, if you expect precise terminology to be displayed on this forum, you're setting yourself up for disappointment.  I rarely see even the "experts" use proper terminology in a consistent, thoughtful manner.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner Why would you say such a thing ? 
**"...computer programming may not be for you."**
Damn you destroyed me, i was just a rookie when a posted this.
What you said is not encouraging at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify the length to print or terminate the string. Otherwise, you will invoke *undefined behavior*. Try this, in which the latter method is implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXCHAR 8

int main(void)
{
    char password[MAXCHAR + 1]; /* allocate one more element for terminating null-character */
    int i;
    char c;

    printf("Insert password: MAX 8 CHARS!\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i <= MAXCHAR; i++){
        c = getchar();

        if(i == MAXCHAR){
            break;
        }
        else{
            password[i] = c;
        }
    }
    password[MAXCHAR] = '\0'; /* terminate the string */

    printf("%s\n", password);
}
```

Some people say that the `if(i == MAXCHAR){ break; }` part doesn't look good, so here is another code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXCHAR 8

int main(void)
{
    char password[MAXCHAR + 1]; /* allocate one more element for terminating null-character */
    int i;

    printf("Insert password: MAX 8 CHARS!\n\n");
    /* read exactly 8 characters. To improve, breaking on seeing newline or EOF may be good */
    for(i = 0; i < MAXCHAR; i++){
        password[i] = getchar();
    }
    password[MAXCHAR] = '\0'; /* terminate the string */
    getchar(); /* to match number of call of getchar() to the original: maybe for consuming newline character after 8-digit password */

    printf("%s\n", password);
}
```

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= MAXCHAR; i++)`..are you sure? is not it, like 9 elements? you can get rid of the whole `break;` thingy....

Comment: @SouravGhosh there is a hack inside the loop to work around it :) Update: Yeah, you have seen it. A classic example of putting a patch without understanding the root cause.

Comment: @SouravGhosh 9 characters will be read but only 8 characters + null-character will be stored. It may be weird specification, but I don't think it is invalid.

Comment: @MikeCAT And it will mislead the user, thinking his password is 9 characters.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It may be 8 characters + newline, but password with 7 characters or less isn't allowed here... What does "MAX" mean?

Comment: @MikeCAT Based on *your* code it's 8+newline.  Anyway, this whole `if-break` thing is a nonsense.

Comment: I got two question now:
1) Why "if(i == MAXCHAR){ break; }" doesn't look good ?
2)Ok but why that goddamn smile appears only if the limit is eight ? o.O
And why does it appear always ?

Comment: @ClaudioPisa 1) Thinking again, I don't think the code is so bad because using it you can merge two calls of `getchar()` into one. 2) By chance if you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why do you think this whole `if-break` thing is a nonsense.?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer you already received from [MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4062354/mikecat), an alternate approach would be to make use of [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the user input.

In that case , you don't need to keep a count on each character input, you can specify the max size and get done with it. Something like

```
 fgets(password, MAXCHAR, stdin);
```

can get the job done for you, minus the looping and assignment for each element.

One thing to remember, however, for shorter inputs than the given length, `fgets()` reads and stores the trailing newline also, you may need to get rid of that manually. Read the linked man page for more ideas.

That said, `main()` is a very *bad* and *almost non-standard* for hosted environments. You should use `int main(void)`, at least to conform to the standards.

Comment: `fgets`of `MAXCHAR` characters actually reads `MAXCHAR - 1` characters and uses the last one for the string end. It will also stop reading after the `MAXCHAR-1`th character has been seen, regardless of whether it was a newline or not. So with `fgets` you might run into the problem of accepting maximum 6 chars+newline or 7 chars (with a newline still remaining in the stream), which makes it even harder to hit the exact maximum character count.

Comment: @tofro and why do you think that? 1) `MAXCHAR` needs to be adjusted, it's not a fixed value. 2) You have to check and remove the trailing newline, if any, then check for the string length, what's the issue there? 3) `with a newline still remaining in the stream` that is not supposed to be of much concern here, is not it?

Comment: @SouravGosh The main thing is: `fgets` will not wait for confirmation of the password by the user once he has supplied the maximum amount of characters - Which is at least irritating, but can lead to all sorts of errors. Works, but I would never use that in production code.

Answer (score 0):

All C-style strings have a terminal `\0` character (value 0). This is unique from any other character value, so it can be used to signal the end of the string. The smiley face you observe is just a part of some neighboring memory block that happens to have a null character after the first byte (hence there being only one extra character). The `printf` function reads bytes from the string given to it, until it sees the `\0`. To solve your problem, you can either write

```
password[MAXCHAR] = '\0';
```

(You will need to reserve one additional byte in your array, for the `\0`).

Or you can zero-out your array from the get-go:

```
char password[MAXCHAR + 1] = { };
```

Or using `memset`:

```
memset(password, '\0', sizeof password);
```